# UIView masking on iOS 10

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch, uiview

I have a `UIView` subclass called `myView` and a `UIViewController` called `myViewController`.

I'm adding `myView` as a subclass inside `myViewController`, and I also mask `myView` subview inside its file.

The problem is that when I'm masking, the view just completely disappears.

Anybody knows why?

Thanks!

My code:

**`myViewController`**:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
     let theView = myView(frame: CGRectZero)
     theView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
     self.view.addSubview(theView)

     theView.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.bottomAnchor).active = true
     theView.leftAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.leftAnchor).active = true
     theView.rightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.rightAnchor).active = true
     theView.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.17).active = true
}
```

**`myView`**:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {

        super.layoutSubviews()
        let ev = UIView(frame: self.bounds)
        ev.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        ev.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.addSubview(ev)

        ev.rightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.rightAnchor).active = true
        ev.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.bottomAnchor).active = true
        ev.leftAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.leftAnchor).active = true
        ev.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1.5).active = true

        let myPath: CGPathRef = PocketSVG.pathFromSVGFileNamed("CategoriesBar").takeUnretainedValue() //Creating a CGPath object using a  3rd party API
        var transform: CGAffineTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(self.frame.size.width / 754.0, self.frame.size.height / 220.0) //Resizing it

        let transformedPath: CGPathRef = CGPathCreateMutableCopyByTransformingPath(myPath, &transform)! //Creating a re-sized CGPath

        let myShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        myShapeLayer.path = transformedPath
        myShapeLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd

        let myMaskedView = UIView(frame: self.frame)
        myMaskedView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        myMaskedView.layer.mask = myShapeLayer
        ev.maskView = myMaskedView //THE PROBLEM. If I remove this line the view is visible (but it isn’t masked), but when I don’t the view just completely disappears!
}
```

Note: the problem happened when I updated to iOS 10, on iOS 9 everything is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

'`self.view.layoutSubviews()`' in '`viewDidLoad()`' before implementing '`UIView`' worked for me.  It has something to do with viewcontroller lifecycle changes in iOS10.

Comment: Well, I was fixing my problem for about an hour and what I understood is now you should be very careful with `self.bounds` `self.frame` etc. cause in my case I was manipulating `UIView` mask when its frame, which was ok in swift 2.3, became (0, 0, 1000, 1000), so I fixed it by printing `UIView.bounds`, placing it in different functions and in the end found a way to make it be not (0, 0, 1000, 1000) (by adding `self.view.layoutSubviews()`). My guess is that your problem is similar, but I am not 100% sure.

Comment: `self.bounds`: (0.0, 0.0, 375.0, 113.5)
`self.frame`: = (0.0, 553.5, 375.0, 113.5)